# Increment set<string>

Tags: android

I'm in the process of making a game with 6 different challenges; every challenge I put it in different class. Every time I play the game, the challenge that showed up won't be same because I randomized the class and I don't want the same challenge showing up again (redundant).Can anyone help me ?
This is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActiv extends Activity{
private static final String msg = null;
private Random random = new Random();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("set", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = pref2.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.add(dragsandal.class.getName());
    set.add(Terimakasih.class.getName());
    set.add(Ludah.class.getName());
    set.add(Permisi.class.getName());
    set.add(Tolong.class.getName());
    set.add(Maaf.class.getName());
    editor2.putStringSet("set", set);
    editor2.apply();
    set = pref2.getStringSet("set", set);
    Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>();
    for (String s : set) {
        try{
            classes.add(Class.forName(s));
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ignore){
        }
    }
    List<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>(classes);
    Class item = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    Log.d(msg, "remove:" + item);
    set.remove(item.getName());
    Log.d(msg, "set " + set.size());
    editor2.putStringSet("st", set);
    editor2.apply();

    Intent m = new Intent(MainActiv.this,item);
    startActivity(m);
}
```

}

Below:This is the class which want to acces the change of set. Skor.java

```
public class Skor extends Activity {
private static final String msg = null;
ArrayList<Class> nama = new ArrayList<Class>();
private Random random = new Random();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.skor);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lanjutkan);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            SharedPreferences pref2 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("set", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = pref2.edit();
            set = pref2.getStringSet("set", set);
            Log.d(msg, "set " + set.size());
            Set<Class> classes = new HashSet<Class>();
            for (String s : set) {
                try {
                    classes.add(Class.forName(s));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
                }
            }
            List<Class> list = new ArrayList<Class>(classes);
            Class item = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
            Log.d(msg, "class:" + item);
            //no redundan
            set.remove(item.getName());
            editor2.putStringSet("set", set);
            editor2.apply();
            Log.d(msg, "set " + set.size());
            Intent main = new Intent(Skor.this, item);
            startActivity(main);
        }
    });
}}
```

Set in MainActivity.java has been successed to remove the random item. But in Skor.java the set didn't remove and going back to original set

Comment: How do I increment the set<string> ?

Comment: Please show the classes and methods which contain the code shown.

Comment: What is `Class`? Is this a class which you created? If so, I strongly suggest that you find a different name since Java has a built-in class named `Class`.

Comment: Overall this sounds like some design issues. You need to design your classes so they can communicate data easily. However, you have not provided enough detail about the classes and their methods for us to give suggestions. Please provide more detail about the classes involved here.

Comment: What do you mean by _"increment"_?

Comment: I've edited the code @Code-Apprentice

Comment: like i++ @HiI'mFrogatto

Comment: @JatiDyah Would `++` operator make sense when it is applying to a `Set<String>`?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. The title has the word "increment", but it doesn't make sense to increment a `Set`. You can only increment numbers. Also, the body of your question asks about removing elements from a set, but has nothing about incrementing.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of storing class names in SharedPreferences? What are these classes used for in the rest of your program?

Comment: Have you considered using a file or database instead of SharedPreferences?

Comment: I know it doesnt make sense. But it seems like that, doesnt mean i want to use ++. I just wanna know what i should i do when one of element the set<string> has been remove and the new size of set<string> will used in another class. @HiI'mFrogatto

Comment: Methods that can be used on a set (i.e. add(), remove(), size()) are listed here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Set.html